# Constrained optimization on a sphere - finding a specific curve

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, optimal-control

Consider a sphere with a point $A$ and point $B$ on it. In addition there are $k$ points on that sphere we call forbidden points. I am looking for a curve on that sphere from $A$ to $B$ that does not intersect with neighborhoods (loseley speaking circles) of the $k$ points.

The curve I am looking for should be at least differentiable and somehow "optimal", e.g. the shortest possible one.

Can anyone give me hints or refer to related literature?

I am dealing with an optimal control problem and found an Ansatz to solve it and now i would like to try another Ansatz.

Comment: You could discretize a large number of roughly equally spaced points on the sphere, define links to neighbors to the North/South/East/West that do not intersect a forbidden region, then run a shortest path solver over that graph.  The true solution can likely be obtained by "pulling the string" to smooth out the path by tracing around boundaries.

Comment: What Ansatz did you find?